# Center a floated link inside a div

Tags: css, centering

I've a div with only a min-width that extends itself like it is 100% width.

Inside it i have a link left  floated and I'm going crazy finding a way to center it inside the div.

How can i do this without changin it's float?

Oh and the link hasn't a defined with

EDIT:

I've tried with:

I gave the container a text-align: center,
removed the float nad it gets centerd but not aligned with others element and i've tried using display: inline and vertical-align.

For the code i'm trying to center the "Project name" here http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

Comment: yes, without float: left it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/cU2ff/
```

### EDIT

http://jsfiddle.net/cU2ff/1/

I came up with this, don't know if it's gonna help. The float: left property doesn't do anything but I left it there

```
<div id='container'>
 <a id='projectName' href='#'>Ciaoasdsa da sda sd asd adsa</a>
 <ul id='menu'><li>li1</li><li>li2</li></ul>
 <p id='login'><a>asd</a></p>
</div>

#container 
{
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

li { float: left; } 

#menu, #login { border: 1px solid black; }

#menu{ float:left; }

#login { float:right; }

#projectName
{
 text-align: center;
 border:1px solid red;
 padding:3px;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 float: left;
}
```

### EDIT

http://jsfiddle.net/cU2ff/2/

wrap it with a div and give it the id projectName

Comment: perfect but my ink can't have a declared with or a 100% one but it should adapt depending on the text. I've updated the question with more details and a link

Comment: mmm may I just ask why float: left is a requirement?

Comment: I wrapped it in a div and gave it the id projectName. no css change, check it out and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I usually used this too center my links within the div.

```
div.name a
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the html you are talking about it is a little difficult to give you an answer, but try this if it is just text inside the link.

```
a{
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
}
```

Comment: oh but so the a get the whole width and it shouldn't

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this

```
a{
margin:0 auto;
}
```